# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Here NoteEditor is a view.onSaveNoteCommand call from Contoller.
I have created a Model In which there is Four Field(title,id,dateCreated,narrative).

```
   onSaveNoteCommand: function(){
        console.log("onsaveCommand");
        var noteEditor= this.getNoteEditor();       
        var newValues= noteEditor.getValues();
        noteEditor.setRecord(newValues);
        var currentNote= noteEditor.getRecord();
        currentNote.set("title",newValues.title);// Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

        currentNote.set("narrative",newValues.narrative);
        var errors= currentNote.validate();
        if(!errors.isValid()){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField("title")[0].getMessage(),Ext.emptyFn);
        currentNote.reject();
        return;
    }
    var notesStore = Ext.getStore("NotesSave");
    if(notesStore.findRecord('id',currentNote.data.id)==null){
        notesStore.add(currentNote);
    }
    notesStore.sync();
    notesStore.sort([{ property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'DESC'}]);
    this.activateNotesList();
},
```

Comment: Evidently `noteEditor.getValues()` is returning `undefined`. I can't tell why looking at this code you posted only.

Comment: noteEditor.getValues() is not returning null value.Here is problem that Set is peroperty of undefind.
set method unable to set the value of title.

Comment: Then it's not returning a record but something else. Is this that you are calling? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-getValues That returns an array not an `Ext.data.Model`

Comment: No that is returning record because i check it to print in console.
Here i want to that if some fill the title and narrative then i want to save it in my Store thats by i want to set method to save the attribute.

Comment: Take a look at currentNote in the debugger. Does it have a "set" method? Such kind of errors are generally easy to trace by using the debugger.